# the plugin org.jetbrains.android failed to save settings and has been disabled

Tags: android-studio

When starting Android Studio 1.2 I get the error message:

> the plugin org.jetbrains.android failed to save settings and has been
>   disabled

I tried restarting and even downloaded the latest Android plugin but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem which I just solved by the following steps:

1. Exit Android Studio
2. Check if you have 2 directories `.AndroidStudio1.2` and `.AndroidStudio`
3. Delete Android `.AndroidStudio` directory
4. Start Android Studio and open another working project
5. Exit Android Studio and Start your current project.

Hope this will helps you too.
If the above doesn't help , try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071697/1503155).

Comment: Where is .AndroidStudio Folder?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had with this is because my project name had an escaped character in it. The Project was exported as Archie's Blah, which was turned into Archie\'sBlah, which was causing problems (even if it wasn't actively complaining about it)