# Android Studio 3.0 - Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Yesterday I was updated my Android Studio version to stable version 3.0 then I am started getting this errors in my studio and unable to build the app.

> Unable to save plugin settings: The plugin org.jetbrains.android failed to save settings and has been disabled. Please restart Android Studio

But I forcefully enabled all plugins in my Studio by going to File-->Settings-->Plugins --> All are enabled.

I tried by deleting .AndroidStudio/* folder as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071697/2462531) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30163947/2462531)

I tried by Invalidate and Restart and Enable Android Support as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30364053/2462531)

And also tried by uninstalling studio and reinstalled latest stable version 3.0 one from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

But none of them are working, Can any one suggest me any alternate solution for this.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161910/the-plugin-org-jetbrains-android-failed-to-save-settings-and-has-been-disabled

Comment: @GowthamanM As I said I tried this already.. If read my question completely you can saw this link

Comment: Any solution for this yet?

Comment: 5 years and no solution, what kind of program is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I resolved by creating new Android project and moved my all files into it. This issue got because of existing settings in the old project.

It may useful for someone.

**Update:**

Go to File--> Project Structure --> Check Use Embedded JDK (Recommended)

Ref:[image]

Comment: Yeah, well this is NOT what I want to hear. I want to hear an EASY way to fix AS 3.0.1's (several) problems.

Comment: This was similar to the first of several problems I had. I don't recall jetbrains being mentioned. I had upgraded to 3.0.1 and on came the errors. I don't remember how I got rid of this error. I think I did what it said: Exit and restart AS. Then came other error messages. In the long run, I got errors about `facets` and a bunch of `plugins` that couldn't run because Android Studio plugin couldn't run. I couldn't get to File > Settings. Gradle listed all the plugins that wouldn't load and had a link about a "balloon" at the bottom of the list. I clicked it, enabled AS plugin, ajd all was well.

Comment: Got this problem after updating today, then side installing 3.1.4. Mine is already checked so I don't think it's the embedded

Comment: @behelit have you tried `by creating new Android project and moved my all files into it`?

Answer (score 7):

Faced the same problem on v3.5.3. Resolved by deleting `.idea` folder.

Comment: This is common when you copy a project folder from windows to mac for example. Removing the .idea folder regenerates it with ideal environment variables

Answer (score 4):

@DSlomer64

I found an easier way.

Instead of 'creating new Android project and moved my all files into it' as Shylendra Madda did, I merely deleted the .idea folder.

1) Go to File--> Settings -->Plugins     Disable any plugins not loaded (i.e. red in color)

2)  Enable the one plugin, Android Support

3)  Right-click on your 'app' directory (contains your module gradle.build file) in Android Studio and select 'Show in Explorer'  --- this opens that directory.

4) Quit Android Studio. Get out of any and all instances of Android Studio to allow you to then delete the fold, .idea, in that directory.

5) Restart AS, you'll notice the project will not come up -- you'll have to pick in the dialog window that appears. That's ok. Pick it, and it will 'rebuild' the folder, .idea.

6) Go to File--> Settings -->Plugins     Enable any and all plugins

7) You won't get the message ever again...  ;)

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. Very detailed and it did it for me. Some steps weren't necessary for me but I'm sure they will be for others.

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue related to the antivirus:

1. If you want to do it the easy way:
   Windows Defender>Virus & Threat protection>Ransomware Protection> Unable the
   protection.
2. If you want to do it the best way (considering your security):
   Windows Defender>Virus & Threat protection>Ransomware Protection> APP through
   monitored folder access> Add allowed APP> last blocked app> Add the
   Studio64/Studio.exe (You need to enable hidden folders in order to open ProgramData)
   Then, go to your Windows Explorer `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows  Defender\Scans\History` Delete everything in that folder.
3. Check if your project's folder is in the exclusions folder. Windows Defender>
   Virus & Threat protection> Virus & threat protection settings> Add or remove
   exclusions. Android Studio should work
   fine now :D.

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue by disabling Ransomware protection (controlled folder access) in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is because your project in a drive that you don't have sufficient permissions to access. I faced that problem so I recreate my project in home directory (Ubuntu) instead ntfs drive and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Windows Defender Security Center.
2. Click on Virus & threat protection → Ransomware Protection.
3. Disable the radio button:

   [image]

Comment: Agreed with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me, because I installed the plugin that cause my AS error. mine AS 4.1.

How to trace the plugin issue

1. First, go to idea.log, it is located at `AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\log` or you can use help -> show log in explorer
2. Check what cause the error, for me it is because plugin i installed from balloon tip for my NDK project (Android.MK) it is called dockdockgo. here is the error I got

   ```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class name.kropp.intellij.makefile.MakefileTargetKeyIndexKt
   ```
3. After you got what makes you AS problem then delete the plugin at `AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins`

I have check that the plugins cause AS freezing from [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-24013) and [here](https://github.com/intuit/DockDockBuild/issues/32).
Lesson learned, never install plugin recommendation from balloon tips unless you have do some research with the plugins first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- Rename the folder where the project is in
- Open the project in Android Studio (now you'll have to browse for it)
- Wait until it's synced and close the project
- Rename the folder back to original

That solved it for me. Just deleting the idea folder and invalidating caches did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the .idea\workspace.xml file that was not saved properly (presumably). There were two files:
       workspace.xml and workspace.xml~

I just renamed:
       workspace.xml to workspace-old.xml and
       workspace.xml~ to workspace.xml

And things were back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS:
Open

1. **Terminal**
2. **cd your_project_folder**
3. **sudo chmod -R 777 ./**

That means you are giving full permission to your project folder. You can modify permission level like **644**, **755** etc.

Comment: What about windows users?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the `latest android studio 4 ( AUG 2022)` on `MAC`!

1. delete `build` files `app>build` and root `build` and `.idea` and `.gradle`
2. rename the project directory
3. open another project and after that open your project again in a new window.

Comment: I faced it too. Turns out, all the local code change I made, were gone. It reverted to an older git state. Thankfully I was able to revert it back.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at `C:/user/yourPCname/.android/debug.keystore.lock`

if the size of this file is `0KB`, just delete it and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just `invalidate caches and restart`. It helped me