# How to save required plugins settings and ask other user to install plugins, when opening the project?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, plugins

I am installing some android plugins using android studio in a project.I uploaded that project to git. Now how can I save all my plugins list and push that to git along with project , by mentioning somewhere like gradle, So that who ever clones that project and opens in android studio should be asked to install those plugins or they should be installed automatically?

Is there any solution for that, Let me know if you did not get my question.

I read [Android Studio "Unable to save plugin settings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040295/android-studio-unable-to-save-plugin-settings) question in stack overflow, but did not get how to apply to my problem

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve by code, just associate some key with each plugins and look for that key in your application while opening, if the required keys are not available available, download them and update your key registry.

Comment: Thankyou @Sanjit I did not get you exactly, Can u tell example use case for any sample library?

Comment: Refer this discussion which explains how you can load jars(in your case plugins) dynamically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime   -You have to add your plugins based upon some requirement that logic should be in your code

Comment: So you are asking me to keep saved plugin files in repo and load them in project?

Comment: Yes, do you have any problem with that? You can check maven projects as an example also http://smecsia.me/2013/07/29/loading-plugins-using-aether/

Comment: Is there any chance, for me prompt user to download from settings->plugins, instead of saving files with in project?